# Как найти точку на смещённой окружности?

Tags: svg, геометрия, d3.js

Пытаюсь сделать по теореме Пифагора, но при смещённой окружности вообще не считает.

Путь фигуры:

```
 let d = `M${0},${0}
   v${-p.height}
   a${p.horizontal},${p.vertical},0,0,1,${p.width},0
   v${p.height}
   h${-p.width}`;
```

Круг, который должен отобразиться на окружности:

```
circle.enter()
  .append('circle')
  .merge(circle)
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${this.svg_height})`)
  .attr('r', 1)
  .style("fill", "red") 
  .attr('class', 'circle')
  .attr('cx', 0)
  .attr('cy', - ( Math.sqrt( ((p.width/2) * (p.width/2)) - p.horizontal * p.horizontal ) + p.horizontal) );
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы.

Comment: эту точку можно не считать, а получить посчитанную браузером, если эта арка будет отдельно от остального пути, то еще и очень просто

Comment: кто-нибудь вообще понял о чем речь? найти какую-то точку, на окружности которую сместили не понятно относительно чего?

Comment: @teran я понял чего хочет получить автор, а вот про смещение - это уже полёт фантазии

Comment: @teran здесь окружность больше ширины всей фигуры. Центр окружности расположен за пределами фигуры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно найти любую точку на пути, по смещению от начала:

```js
let p = document.querySelector('path');
let c = document.querySelector('circle');
let len = p.getTotalLength();       // узнаем полную длину пути
let pt = p.getPointAtLength(len/2); // берем точку на половине пути
console.log(pt.x, pt.y);
c.setAttribute('cx', pt.x);
c.setAttribute('cy', pt.y);
```

```html
<svg viewbox="50 50 300 100" height="88vh">
  <path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M 100,100 a150,150,0,0,1,100,0"/>
  <circle fill="none" r=3 stroke="red"/>
</svg>
```

PS: Если вы ищите верхнюю точку всей фигуры, её можно получить через `getBBox()` или `getBoundingClientRect()`

```js
let p = document.querySelector('path');
let c = document.querySelector('circle');
let bbox = p.getBBox();      
console.log(bbox);
c.setAttribute('cx', bbox.x + bbox.width/2);
c.setAttribute('cy', bbox.y);
```

```html
<svg viewbox="50 50 300 100" height="88vh">
  <path fill="none" stroke="red" d="M 100,100 a150,150,0,0,1,100,0"/>
  <circle fill="none" r=3 stroke="red"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: А можно взять длину от части пути, длину только `a`?

Comment: @doox911 нет, но можно нарисовать невидимую и взять от нее, это то что относится к получению точки в целом, Вашу не сложно и посчитать

Comment: `getBoundingClientRect()` -  сработает только если изображение равно ширине и высоте?

Comment: @doox911 Вам какая точка таки нужна?

Comment: сейчас по центру, но может такое случиться, что и любая на видимой части окружности.

Comment: @doox911 тогда берите через длину.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92739/discussion-between-doox911-and-stranger-in-the-q).